# Pressure variation in a Constant Volume Gas Thermometer

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

In the operation of a Constant Volume Gas Thermometer, the pressure of the gas in the bulb at the triple point of water ($P_{TP}$) is varied by removing some of the gas in the bulb. It is stated (see Zemansky and Dittman, *Heat and Thermodynamics*, 6th ed., p. 16) that by removing some of the gas, $P_{TP}$ has a smaller value.

Pressure is an intensive quantity, then how does removal of a certain mass of gas reduce $P_{TP}$ ?

Comment: I suspect that there is an error in the text.  The triple point of a substance is supposed to be a constant, where there is one and only one temperature, and one and only one pressure, where all three phases of the substance can exist in equilibrium.

Comment: In the book, the empirical temperature scale is defined as the value of 273.16K($P/P_{TP}$) as $P_{TP}\rightarrow0$, therefore both $P$ and $P_{TP}$ must decrease in order that their ratio approaches a constant.

Comment: Is there a practical application in defining an empirical temperature scale?  Also, perhaps you can give a bit more context in your posting.

Comment: Practical application is the establishment of a temperature scale via a thermometer which is independent of choice of working substance (gas in this case). The Constant Volume Gas Thermometer fits the bill, in the limit $P_{TP}\rightarrow0$.